# Formula error of hard-coded structured references with Excel tables

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I'm trying to use structured references with Excel tables https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e.

If I copy-paste the formula like `=DeptSales[[Sales Person]:[Region]]` in a cell, Excel returns an "There's a problem with this formula..." error.

[image]

One solution is to choose the `Sales Person` that the intellisense proposes:

[image]

I don't understand why hard-coded `Sales Person` is not accepted. Could anyone help?

PS: the version of my Excel for Windows:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to cast doubt on the square brackets your keyboard inserts? This might be the case if you use a non-English version of Windows or a non-English keyboard. You can ascertain the nature of the bracket with `=Code("[")` which should return 91 for the type of opening bracket structured references require.

Comment: Often, the issue will be that the column header is not exactly the same as the hard-coded version. One or the other may contain a space or non-printing character.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why dont you type = in the cell where you are putting the formula, then select the target cells with your mouse? Then it should work correctly.
2. I dont see the calculations that you want to do? Is it count or sum or something?
   Please see my example below. It works fine.

[image]